# How much is a Stack Exchange reputation point worth, roughly, to the company?

Tags: support, reputation, business-model

The Stack Exchange websites are run for profit, and they work by publishing questions and answers that are valuable by two measures: the number of clicks they gain, and how many points they get given by users. It's in the company's interest for the two measures to stay correlated; and while the first correlates with profit, the second correlates with reputation points because every time a contribution is marked as good its author gains reputation.

So I wondered whether the company uses a rough conversion rate between reputation points and US dollars, and if so what that rate is, or if they don't use a rate or don't want to reveal it then what the rate might reasonably be. Of course the relationship might not be linear, so for example if a 1k-rep user's work is worth $100, a 100k-rep user's work might be worth $20000 and Jon Skeet's 1.1M rep...well I don't know!

For comparison, here are some articles on the value of a "like" on other social media sites:

"[What is the Real Value of the Facebook “Like”?](https://www.taylordigital.com/blog/real-value-facebook-like/)"
"[What is the value of a ‘Like?’](http://marketingland.com/what-is-the-value-of-a-like-212700)"
"[What’s the Value of a Like?](https://hbr.org/2017/03/whats-the-value-of-a-like)" (Harvard Business Review - they cite a recent report showing that 80% of the US companies surveyed were "unable to quantify the value of their social media efforts", but they are looking at companies that advertise on Facebook rather than Facebook itself)

**Edit**
A quick and dirty calculation using

(estimated value of company, $500m or £400m) / (estimated total rep, 2 x 10<sup>9</sup> points)

gives a figure of $250 or £200 per 1000 rep.

Comment: How do you imagine conversion of rep to dollars would take place?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - give me 10k in rep - will pay 1$ :P

Comment: Oh, so it's like credit card airplane "miles". :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I'm not talking about literal exchange but nominal conversion, because reputation points do correspond roughly, perhaps very roughly, with the company's profit or at least its income.

Comment: @ruffle not really. Advertisers don't care about overall reputation, just about amount of visitors to the site. More visitors mean more chance of some clicking ads and buying their products.

Comment: **Assoc bonus = Free $$$** on each site! Am I right?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - But what I'm calling the total amount of goodness in the questions and answers (Q&A expertise) as measured by rep points must bear some relation to the site's ability to attract visitors, which flows from the amount of content and its goodness as perceived by visitors and potential visitors.

Comment: $500m umm.... why not $10000000000000000000000000000000 and be done with? That's just totally absurd.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - You should have thought for a bit longer before mocking. When the company raised $40m of series D funding in January 2015, mostly from Andreessen-Horowitz, its value [was estimated at $459.19 million](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-revenue-and-valuation-of-Stack-Overflow). Rounding to 1 significant figure and working on the assumption that its value hasn't increased above $550 million in the past 2.5 years gives an estimated worth of $500m.

Comment: Well, so I mock the whole system that evaluates the value of websites. Yes, I also mock the value of Facebook being billions upon billions. But I'm afraid I can't mock reality, so you're right. :)

Comment: Stack Exchange is worth about 0.1% of Facebook, which has a market capitalisation of [around $500bn](https://ycharts.com/companies/FB/market_cap). There's big money in advertising :) According to [Alexa.com](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackexchange.com), SE is the 135th most popular website in the world.

Answer (score 28):

**The following suggests that a user with a reputation score of 100,000 has done about £20,000 ($27,000) of work for the company.**

Pending the investigation of the applicability of Bathsheba's excellent suggested model, I took a sample of 25 users of Stack Overflow and for each of them I looked at their reputation score and the number of "people reached". The sample comprised the authors of the five answers posted here prior to this one, along with the lowest-score users on each of pages 1-5, 51-55, 101-105 and 201-205 of the listing of SO users by rep.

A linear regression with the intercept set at 0 rep = 0 views gives a goodness of fit R<sup>2</sup> = 0.833 and a figure of 77 views per rep point. So if 1000 views are worth $1 to an advertiser, that's $77x per 1000 rep where x is the average number of pages a visitor views here.

R<sup>2</sup> jumps to 0.89 if two very high views-to-rep users are removed.

An estimate based on what's been written so far would be maybe $80-$400 (£60-£300) per 1000 rep, or $16-$80 (£12-£60) for a full 200-rep day. Since the estimate of the company's value at $500 million is based on the idea that it's going to be around for some time, and since the number of views of any much-viewed page is going to increase during that time, a reasonable estimate of the amount of value corresponded to by reputation should be in the higher part of that interval. I would suggest a ratio giving the following figures:

- a 200-rep day gives the company about £40 ($54).
- a rep score of 1000 is for about £200 ($270) worth of work
- a rep score of 100,000 is for about £20000 ($27000) worth of work

(I'd be grateful for some help making a data query for "people reached" against "reputation" points for a bigger sample.)

[image]

Answer (score 26):

> I wondered whether the company uses a rough conversion rate between reputation points and US dollars

No, we don't. We don't attach monetary value to reputation. Never did, never will.

It doesn't make any sense to do so.

In the same way that Twitter likes don't have any inherent monetary value for Twitter.

Comment: *"twitter/facebook likes don't have any inherent monetary value."* - I'm not so sure if TWTR / FB shareholders as well as advertising customers share your opinion, there :)

Comment: @LukasEder - Give me a conversion rate then :P

Comment: Well, YouTube views do have actual monetary value.

Comment: @Oded: I once paid 10$ for 50 likes.

Comment: @LukasEder - did it make you happier?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't make any sense to do so? They are some kind of measure of the combined goodness of questions and answers which is what builds the brand and gets the company sales.

Comment: Why do you think it does make sense to do so, @ruffle? The two things are not correlated.

Comment: @Oded - Imagine if Twitter and Facebook contributors stopped issuing likes. That would be a problem. The value isn't just in views but in views times the amount of enjoyment a viewer has while viewing, which can be measured, however roughly, by likes.

Comment: @Oded - I give some kind of train of thought connecting rep with money in the question. I'm not sure which link in the chain you would question the most. The total amount of perceived goodness of questions and answers correlates with both income and total reputation points, I would say.

Comment: Mostly - the link you are drawing between clicks and points. Not seeing the directly correlation that you seem to believe exists. Regardless - you asked about what we do - and we don't do that - we don't use any sort of rate.

Comment: @ruffle - I guess I most object to how you conflate the mechanics of the site (reputation/points) with the value of the site to its users/investors/the company.

Comment: @Oded There are people you can actually go to that will like your page/content for $X per like (because this can give the page/content more attention via facebook's algorithms and for many companies that content is effectively advertising).  There *is* a monetary value for likes on facebook.

Comment: @Servy - but do FB/Twitter (the companies) attach monetary value to them?

Comment: @Oded For Facebook, yes.  You can pay FB (not a third party) to promote your page/content in order to get it more likes, so there is in fact a monetary value *to the company* for them (because there's a monetary value to their customers that they can fulfill).

Comment: @Oded: *"did it make you happier?"* - would money make you happier? :)

Comment: The company's arrangement with its army of unpaid helpers seems to be as follows: **1) the helpers work for the company; 2) in return, the company allows them access to some tools to carry out the work with**. A neat way to build an asset worth $500m!

Comment: @ruffle - what you are ignoring is that what is produced (questions and answers) become a common good. They are not the property of the company (the platform is, but not the user generated content). There's a reason we provide a data dump for all the sites.

Comment: I will also add that your last comment is incredibly cynical, @ruffle - and that if you don't like it, you don't have to participate (we don't force anyone to participate, after all).

Comment: Common? The [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) require that if a user takes what somebody other than themselves has posted here and publishes *or otherwise uses* it somewhere else (on the internet or *anywhere*) they are obliged to indicate that it comes "from the SE network", and if they use it on the internet to hyperlink to it here. If the total value made by parties other than the company from what is published here is $5000 that would be 0.001% of the $500m the company has made. A 100k rep makes the company $8000-$40000. I hope the ad-carrying t-shirts are high quality.

Comment: Nobody has suggested that slavery is involved! :) I am not the cynical party here. Far from it.

Comment: What is it with this obsession  to putting a dollar amount on everything?

Comment: "A 100k rep makes the company $8000-$40000". Based on made up statistics - you have shown 0 correlation. This is all assumptions.

Comment: I haven't "made up" any statistics. I do not have an "obsession". I do not wish to put a dollar amount on "everything". My assumptions on the company's value and the value of having "reached" so many people are reasonable, and I have shown a sample correlation of 0.83, not 0, between rep score and number of people "reached". You sound as though you are little interested in answering the question here, in which case, why post? It's a fact, not an opinion, that the company leverages as a profitable asset the contributions made by thousands of people who unlike yourself are unpaid.

Comment: I'm very curious whether that "never will" statement still holds.

Answer (score 26):

In the last round of funding, 2015, the Stack Exchange valuation was around $460 million [USD].

Total reputation in each of the [top ten sites<sup>*</sup> by number of users](https://stackexchange.com/sites#users):

- [Stack Overflow: 864,255,312](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/701774/stack-overflow-total-reputation)
- [Super User: 36,328,065](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/701778/super-user-total-reputation)
- [Ask Ubuntu: 25,036,905](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/701784/ask-ubuntu-total-reputation)
- [Mathematics: 46,546,816](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/701784/mathematics-total-reputation)
- [Server Fault: 25,748,853](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/701784/total-reputation-across-all-users)
- [Software Engineering: 22,078,489](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/701784/total-reputation-across-all-users)
- [Unix & Linux: 17,511,360](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/701784/total-reputation-across-all-users)
- [Ask Different: 10,203,160](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/701784/total-reputation-across-all-users)
- [English Language and Usage: 15,221,216](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/701784/total-reputation-across-all-users)
- [Android Enthusiasts: 6,027,366](https://data.stackexchange.com/android/query/701784/total-reputation-across-all-users)

So if we assume that reputation value is equal across all sites (it's not, but this is meant to be a quick assessment), and we ignore the fact that we're using 2017 reputation counts applied to a 2015 valuation, and we assume that the content is what makes the company valuable, and that the reputation roughly correlates to content value, then we can sum the reputation, divide by the valuation, and provide a rough ballpark estimate for reputation per USD:

1,068,957,542 / $460,000,000 = 2.32 rep/$

Approximately $0.43 per reputation point.

Of course there are many, many flaws to this method, but it's one way to assign arbitrary value to an arbitrary fake internet point system.

If, for instance, I attempted to sell [my network account (all sites)](https://stackexchange.com/users/2114/adam-davis?tab=flair) to another person, with its 224k of total reputation, I couldn't command a price of $0.43 * 224,000 = $96,320<sup>†</sup>.

If someone purchased Stack Exchange the valuation would be much greater than $460M [USD], however they wouldn't necessarily be buying the reputation of the users, but the content and the userbase itself. When Microsoft purchased Minecraft and LinkedIn they weren't buying a product, they were buying players and users - established customer bases and communities.

So the $0.43 is hugely inflated, however there really is no easy way to accurately gauge the value since there's no market.  We can make up any sort of calculation that we want, but until reputation becomes something easily and widely traded then there's no real way to evaluate its actual value.

<sup>*</sup><sub>I'm ignoring meta.SE for the purposes of this post.</sub>

<sup>†</sup><sub>Interested parties may inquire within.</sub>

Comment: This ignores the infrastructure of the site - servers, codebase, staff etc... as being of any value.

Comment: @Catija Correct. Let's perform a little thought experiment.  What is the value of the site without its content, community, and daily traffic?  What is the value of the content, community, and daily traffic without the backend to support it?  While the backend made the community possible, it should be fairly obvious where the majority of the value lies. I don't intend to devalue the backend, the employees, and the company itself - there's a complex interplay there, but if sold the value would largely be dictated by the content, users, and traffic, and only in small part the support structure.

Comment: "there's no market" - absolutely. Have an upvote.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. It's true that you couldn't sell your account for $96k, but perhaps your work has contributed around that amount of value to the company?

Comment: Well that's a different question.  On SO it says my posts have helped 8.4 million people, which is simply a count of the pageviews of my questions and high ranked answers. In the US pageviews might be worth as much as $1 per 1,000 pageviews in advertising, and with 8.4 million of them I've made Stack Exchange perhaps $8,400 in advertising income over the last decade. I've made over 48k rep on SO itself, so that would be around 6 rep per dollar.  But those pageviews continue to increase so perhaps in another decade I'll have made them another $8k. I don't think I've contributed $96k worth.

Comment: On average each of those visitors will have viewed more than one page, but probably not as many as $96/$8 = 12.

Comment: Well, that shoud be entertaining to recalculate when SE achieves its current trajectory of getting rid of all the significant users..

Comment: As of today the value of the company is better known (1.8 billion). One could update the calculation. I don't think it's really useful but certainly some kind of fun.

Comment: The assumption that reputation points are interchangeable units with some sort of inherent value convertible or comparable to some currency is IMHO baseless. -1.

Answer (score 16):

I have 100k reputation on Super User. Quite literally the only material benefit I have gotten from it is a mug, a T shirt and assorted swag.

SE doesn't make money directly off our answers, but indirectly off the 'reputation' of the site - as a good place to get answers, and leverages that for ancillary products, like careers and advertising.

So, your premise is *probably* flawed, and there's no way to set a dollar value on a user's reputation. This isn't even taking into account things like moderation activity or goodwill from other users.

Comment: I think your second paragraph suggests it does make sense to assign a dollar value to rep. If rep started correlating negatively with profit, or with income, that would be a problem. Rep also correlates with the goodwill from which the company benefits among its contributors, otherwise it wouldn't send promotional goodies to high-rep users. (I'm wondering whether I should estimate a figure for the company's entire worth and divide it by the total number of reputation points :) Horribly quick and dirty, but unless someone suggests a better method...)

Comment: You're basically seeing what you want - basically the abstraction between revenue sources and precise answers is pretty big

Comment: I’ve gotten my current job in large parts due to my Stack Overflow reputation. It’s not worth nothing.

Comment: Well - it can be to *you* -  but getting people getting hired isn't a direct dollar value to SO, or its new owners. the value is very much indirect

Comment: Oh I believe that reputation has literally *zero* value to SO (unlike views etc.). But your answer mentions the benefit *to you*, and puts its value quite below what I think the real value to an individual is. Namely, not just useless swag.

Comment: Well - I've applied to be a CM 4 times, at least once with over 100k rep. I think I'll leave it to folks to judge what the value of the reputation is to SO, considering I've never gotten a chance.  Even if there was, I think the value of the user is mostly in terms of the *intangible*. And I've certainly not gotten that many opportunities due to being a high rep SU or MSE user.

Answer (score 4):

The rough estimation of $250 or £200 per 1000 rep, or $250K or £200K for 100K rep, should be updated in view of the company's recent sale for $1.8bn. That figure is exactly 3.6 times the figure of $500m that was used.

So, using 100K rep as our unit, we can estimate that **a user with 100K rep has done about $90K or £72K of work for the company**.

Or to put it another way, **if you've got 110K rep, you've done about 100k USD of work for the company** - in some cases for the pleasure of being allowed to use the company's tools while working for it, plus the feeling of camaraderie with other workers.

This is based on a figure of 2 x 10^9 for the total number of reputation points. That has probably gone up, which will of course increase the number of reputation points that correspond to a million dollar's worth of work. I am not sure how to estimate the current total number of reputation points.

**Edit**
The above is one part of an outside view. As @Luuklag has rightly said in a comment, among the company's assets there is also the Teams platform which of course has a considerable financial value. It would be good if someone could come up with a reasonable lower bound of an outside view for the value of the work corresponding to 100K reputation points.

Comment: Well this is wayyyy of. Now you asume that all the value the company has comes from its public platform. I bet the Teams business is worth at least the same, or more then the public platform.

Comment: Yes. This was meant as the upper bound of an outside view. (I will edit to make that clear.) A good lower bound is needed.

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with these numbers. Why is the amount for **100k** reputation **1000** times more than for **1k** reputation?

Comment: The estimates from the other answers, multiplied by the factor of 3.6 or so, give something on the order of $1 per reputation point. So, essentially all the numbers in this answer are inflated by one order of magnitude: 110k should be about $100k rather than $1M, etc.

Comment: Not to mention that the amount of total reputation points that the estimates were based on has significantly increased meanwhile: besides new posts and new votes, all points for questions were doubled in the 5 -> 10 switch. Thus, the estimates should be reduced to take that into account.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek - Thanks for this correction. I was out by a factor of 10. Sorry about that. Have now corrected.

Comment: Reputation is a poor measure of value to the company. What about the people who fill out surveys for *no reputation at all*? What about all the people with “Steward” badges? I did 5000+ reviews just on one site that I never got 'paid' for. What about mods and their work? What about avid post editors? As a gamer, it doesn’t surprise me that the roles with the easy-to-measure output are overvalued and the supporting roles are entirely overlooked. A site full of poor quality content and nasty communities wouldn’t be worth as much regardless of how much content and voting it had.

Comment: Perhaps add a reference for *"the company's recent sale for $1.8bn"*? (If nothing else, *[What does the recent sale of Stack Exchange mean for the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365050)*)

Answer (score 2):

The business model of SO as a company is structured in such a way that its income isn't correlated with reputation, so you cannot attach a monetary value to reputation.

SO has two main ways of making money. The first is ads.  The income money SE gets from ads is going to loosely correlate to the amount of views on the site (particularly from *anonymous users*).  Views however, particularly views from anonymous users, isn't going to correlate to reputation.  Lots of actions will earn people lots of reputation, while keeping a fairly low anonymous user count, while other posts will get *enormous* numbers of views, particularly views from anonymous users, without earning the site as much rep (proportionally).  This is in large part because anonymous users can't vote, so their views don't generate rep.

Next there's the Jobs portion of the site. That generates money by matching people looking for jobs with people looking to hire.  There's even *less* correlation here between the revenue generated and rep increases in the site, mostly as a result of the fact that such a small portion of the site's users actually use this feature of the site, but also because usage rates aren't going to correlate with the user's rep (if you only count "active" users).

Comment: Time has caught up with this answer, or it might have been incomplete when it was written. (I don't have all introduction data at the top of my head). There is ofcourse the Enterprise version of SO (where people can host their own version of SO) and SO for teams.

Answer (score 0):

My thought: it's not worth anything.

A comparison between currency and reputation makes little sense so therefore you can't think of the value of Stack Exchange being in "reputation". The mathematicians amongst us would not consider a substitution of reputation for currency as a valid *change of measure*. A couple of reasons in non-technical language:

1. Reputation is not-transferable (with the exception of the bounty "give") between parties so therefore cannot be used as fiat money.
2. Reputation is far too inflationary. Processes that deflate reputation are rare and include downvoting questions (-2), answers (-3), and question and user removal.

It's probable that the **rate of change of total reputation** is correlated with site activity, but that neglects the important facet of folk visiting the sites that don't vote. So I'd submit to you that the rate of change of reputation might be broadly linked to the value of Stack Exchange, not the reputation level itself. In other words, a starting point for a model might be

> v(t) = a (dr(t) / dt) + b(t)

where v is the value, r the reputation, t time, a is a constant and b a function that might end up being too time-dependent for anything useful to be gleaned here. If b turns out to be practically constant or even linear in time then you have stumbled upon something truly brilliant. Not sure where you'd get the data from though to test this model; you can probably get r(t) from a fancy data query, and v(t) from the stock price and shares outstanding data. Good luck!

Comment: Perhaps make downvoting answers as -3 more clear? (-2 for the receiver and -1 for the downvoter.) (Bumping is not a consideration as a new answer has been posted.)